# What does OIO mean in java?

Tags: java, io, netty, nio, terminology

Forgive me I just began to learn Java network programming. I just read [Netty in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/netty-in-action) which mentions a `OIO`.

> NIO is used in this example because it’s currently the most widely used transport, thanks to its scalability and thoroughgoing asynchrony. But a different transport implementation could be used as well. If you wished to use the OIO transport in your server, you’d specify OioServerSocketChannel and OioEventLoopGroup.

I knew the Java IO and NIO already before. But what is the OIO?

I tried to search it in the google but got nothing. Could anyone please help explain what it is?

Comment: You just 'read some tutorial' where? SO isn't a validation site for arbitrary Internet junk.

Comment: Updated it ...Sorry for that.

Comment: Voting to close as resolving this question in a manner unlikely to benefit future readers. It's a stretch. But I'm sticking with it.

Comment: It's crystal clear what the OP asked! Voting to reopen

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OIO stands for Old IO or Blocking IO. In this model each socket or client connection results in spawning a new dedicated thread to handle the request. So, Number or threads == Number of clients/sockets active.

With NIO or New IO, it is possible to have fewer threads serve more number of clients. Here, Number or threads < Number of clients/sockets active.